# Javascript object oriented programming showing undefined

Tags: javascript, oop

I am new to javascript oop
i have been trying to get the desired value but it gives me undefined

```
class person {
  constructor(isGreat, brain, personality) {
    this.isGreat = isGreat;
    this.brain = brain;
    this.personality = personality;
  }
  getDetails(req) {
    this.req = req;

    let dic = {
      isGreat: this.isGreat,
      brain: `they have ${this.brain} brain`,
      personality: `they have ${this.personality} personality`,
    };

    return dic.req;
  }
}

let person0 = new person(true, "massive", "great");
console.log(person0.getDetails("isGreat"));
```

req can get read but dic.req shows undefined

The problem is `console.log` shows undefined.

Comment: apparently you are not assigning `dic.req` anywhere, did you mean to do `return dic[req];` ?

Comment: JavaScript object oriented programming cannot possibly show undefined. It’s just a paradigm, not a concrete program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dic` doesn't have a `req` property. If you want to get a property whose name is stored in `req` variable, use the following syntax:

```
dic[req]
```

Just like accessing array members. In fact, `a.b` and `a['b']` are equivalent in JavaScript.

BTW: The assignment `this.req = req` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the `req` property of your object, not the property with the key stored inside req. You need to use square brackets to get the index stored inside req.

```js
return dic[req]
```

This is because it gets parsed as `dic['isgreat']` rather than `dic['req']`.